# Chrome says 'No manifest detected' when manifest.json is served by Django

Tags: django, progressive-web-apps

I have an SPA with Django on backend. I try to make it a progressive web app. I made a manifest.json and linked it in my index.html:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/static/manifest.json">
```

Chrome can't detect it. My `index.html` is a Django template and is stored in `templates` directory and can't be accessed but by Django route `/`. `Manifest.json` is in `static` directory and served to front-end as a regular static file. I think this is the reason manifest can't be detected - index.html not being accessible. Am I right? If so, could you give me an advice as to how to make it work please?

Comment: What happens when you go to /static/manifest.json directly? Can you see the data?

Comment: Yes, I can access manifest.json in this way. Although, not index.html if that matters.

Comment: Not sure why you think you should be able to access index.html. It's a template, not a page. And the fact of the template being in a separate directory has no relevance at all.

Comment: I hope I didn't make myself obscure. I thought the fact index.html not being available on par with manifest was the reason manifest file can't be loaded.

Comment: What errors are you seeing in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
load static
{% static "manifest.json" %}
```

The syntax here is `{% static "path/relative/to/static/folder" %}`

Comment: Writing {% static "manifest.json" %} results in "/static/manifest.json" so there's no difference.